# How to hide my store procedure and function script from user in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, database-administration

Currently I am using MYSQL 5.6 database.
I have so many store procedures and functions  in one database say database "AppDatabase" for my application which I am developing right now.

What I want to gain is :

Only my program should have all rights for "AppDatabase". I want to prevent any database user to view my store procedures and functions. Even database administrator should not be able to view any store procedure and any function.

I want to secret my database store procedure and function code.

Is it possible to achieve in mysql?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the  [Access Control for Stored Programs and Views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-programs-security.html)